# Why is $A\rightarrow \operatorname{im}(f)$ an epimorphism in an abelian category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

This is an exercise in Ravil Vakil's Algebraic Geometry notes labeled hard

Let $f: A\rightarrow B$ be a morphism in an abelian category. Then $f$ factors through a morphism $f':A\rightarrow \operatorname{im}(f)$ (recall that $\operatorname{im}(f)$ is the (domain of the) kernel of the cokernel of $f$).

**Why is $f'$ an epimorphism?** That is why does $g\circ f'=0$ imply $g=0$ for any $g: \operatorname{im}(f)\rightarrow C$   ?

Comment: Maybe it's helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884741/a-longrightarrow-textim-f-is-an-epimorphism-and-a-cokernel-of-ker-f-long?rq=1

Comment: The difficulty of this depends on the assumptions you're using. The point is that the image is isomorphic to the coimage, and $A$ maps epimorphically on the coimage by definition. Sometimes the fact that the image is the coimage is included as one of the axioms of an abelian category, but I guess not in Vakil.

Comment: Thanks Ben and Kevin. So it seems to be a duplicate, and yes the hard part definitely seems to be showing the natural map coimage to image is an isomorphism.